# Hbase 0.20.6 Can not start master exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ioexception, eofexception

I'm using ***Hbase 0.20.6*** with ***Hadoop 0.21.0*** on ***Ubuntu 10.04 LTS*** and I got can't start master error. (The error is attached at the end of the post from the hbase-root-master-ubuntu.log file)

**Does Hbase 0.20.6 work fine with Hadoop 0.21.0 ?? and if it's NOT, Is there a work around ??**

**What's the problem source ??**

Thanks for your time and consideration.

The Log :

```
java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:775)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:743)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
 at $Proxy0.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:106)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:207)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:170)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:82)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1378)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1390)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:196)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:95)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:195)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.java:94)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.java:78)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.doMain(HMaster.java:1229)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:1274)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:501)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:446)
Fri Dec 24 14:02:12 EET 2010 Starting master on ubuntu
ulimit -n 1024
2010-12-24 14:02:13,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: vmName=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, vmVendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., vmVersion=17.1-b03
2010-12-24 14:02:13,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: vmInputArguments=[-Xmx1000m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode, -Dhbase.log.dir=/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../logs, -Dhbase.log.file=hbase-root-master-ubuntu.log, -Dhbase.home.dir=/usr/lib/hbase/bin/.., -Dhbase.id.str=root, -Dhbase.root.logger=INFO,DRFA, -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/native/Linux-i386-32]
2010-12-24 14:02:13,353 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: My address is ubuntu.ubuntu-domain:60000
2010-12-24 14:02:13,593 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Can not start master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a discussion about this on HBase users mailing list recently, I would suggest reading it.
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201012.mbox/%3CAANLkTimA7UQZAiG0810mtHtGk30x8ejGs+n5+CF8GxQ1@mail.gmail.com%3E

As a summary I would quote what Ryan Rawson of StumbleUpon mentioned in the lists:

> HBase 0.20.6 is likely to run well on hadoop 21.  We have many patches
>   that help bolster durability on top of branch-20-append, and also some
>   may apply to hadoop 21.
>
> What you are possibly running in to is using hadoop 20 jars in hbase
>   0.90 on top of hadoop 21.  Try deleting the hadoop 20 jars and copying
>   in your hadoop 21.
>
> Also consider running cdh3b2+, hadoop 21 is a panned release and no
>   one runs it nor expects it to be run in a production setting.

We are using the HBase 0.90 RCs with Cloudera's CDH3b3 via debian packages. In case you want to consider it please refer to its [installation page](https://docs.cloudera.com/display/DOC/CDH3+Installation#CDH3Installation-InstallingCDH3onDebianSystems) for details. I would also recommend [this page](https://docs.cloudera.com/display/DOC/CDH3+Deployment+on+a+Cluster) for installation on a cluster. Download the latest HBase 0.90 RC from [here](http://people.apache.org/~stack/hbase-0.90.0-candidate-2/).